Why does it seem like it's easier to come back from a 3-0 deficit in a hockey 7 game series to force a game 7
After the 2024 NHL Finals ended with a game 7 victory for Florida, ESPN was showing some serieses in all sports that have 7-game series, teams were down 3-0 only to reverse sweep and win on game 7.  It showed, NBA, NHL, and MLB.  It also showed a bunch of series in all sports where teams who were down 3-0 FORCE game 7 but lose.
It looked to me that most of the serieses ESPN showed going to game 7 after a 3-0 lead were mostly hockey games/series.  I found this wikipedia link that seems to show that same observation too:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_teams_that_have_overcome_3%E2%80%930_series_deficits
Why does it appear like it's easiest to go to game 7 in hockey than other sports that can go 7 games?

At a theoretical level, consider two extremes:
Firstly, the situation where every team has a well-defined skill level and there is no variability, so the better team wins every game. In this case, every series finishes 4-0 and there is zero chance of a game 7.
Second, the situation where each time has an equal chance of winning each game. In this scenario:

We can without loss of generality assert that Team A wins game 1 (p=1)
Team A will win both game 2 and 3 one quarter of the time (p=1/4)
Team B will win games 4, 5 and 6 one eighth of the time (p=1/4 × 1/8 = 1/32)

Therefore one in 32 series will go to a game 7.
Hopefully this example makes it obvious that the higher the variability, the more chance there is of a game 7. Now, is it the case that hockey has a higher variability than baseball and basketball? Don't know, but the fact that hockey has more game 7s than other sports means it may well be.
This analysis ignores a bunch of factors, probably most importantly home ice/field/court advantage. Determining how important that is would be a non-trivial piece of work.
